# Need to add a login to a database for SSMS (Sql server) 2008 r2

Tags: security, login, directory, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I need to add a login to a database for SSMS (Sql server) 2008 r2 
There is an answer to a very similar question here:

How to add users to SQL Server 2008 Management Studio:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364203/how-to-add-users-to-sql-server-2008-managment-studio

There are also answers on other internet sites about this.

**The problem:** They all indicate that I should go to the "login" folder under the "security" folder for the database in SSMS. But my SSMS interface **does NOT have a "login" folder** (directory). There is a "users" folder, but apparently one has to create a login first, then create the user.

Any ideas?

Comment: NOTE:  I originally posted this on 'Stack Overflow' but moved it here to 'Server Fault'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use T-SQL to create logins. Please [see this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Event though it states is for SQL 2017 it should work for your version too.

EXAMPLE (from linked URL):  CREATE LOGIN  WITH PASSWORD = '';
GO